# How can I know the matched alternative in the parent context?

Tags: java, antlr4

How can I know the matched alternative in the parent context , for example in my grammar

```
simpleAssign: name = ID  '=' value = (STRING | BOOLEAN | INTEGER | DOUBLE );
simpleReference: name = ID '=' value = ID;
listAssign: name = ID  '=' value = listString #listStringAssign;
assign: simpleAssign       #simpleVariableAssign
      | listAssign         #listOfVariableAssign
      | simpleReference    #referenceToVariable
      ;
assignVariableBlock: assign +   #assignVariabels;
```

I would like to know in my function enterAssignVariableBlock the matched alternative.

```
@Override public void enterAssignVariableBlock(StudyParser.AssignVariableBlockContext ctx) {

   // switch matched alternative (simpleVariableAssign | listOfVariableAssign | referenceToVariable ) do
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enter...` method would not be called `enterAssignVariableBlock (...)`, but `enterAssignVariabels(...)` since you labeled it as such via `#assignVariabels`.

Although ideally, the parent should not care about the concrete implementation of its children, here's how you could find out the type from the parent rule:

```java
@Override
public void enterAssignVariabels(StudyParser.AssignVariabelsContext ctx) {

    for (StudyParser.AssignContext childCtx : ctx.assign()) {
        if (childCtx instanceof StudyParser.SimpleVariableAssignContext) {
            // #simpleVariableAssign
        }
        else if (childCtx instanceof StudyParser.ListOfVariableAssignContext) {
            // #listOfVariableAssign
        }
        else {
            // #referenceToVariable
        }
    }
}
```